# Facebook login process stuck at permissions.request screen

Tags: facebook, permissions, dialog

I'm having a problem with the Facebook dialog boxes.

When I click on the Facebook button, I'm presented with the Facebook login screen.  When I complete that, the popup changes to the permissions.request (the url in the popup is https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&....").  It shows the three pieces of information that I'm requesting (basic info, about you, and your birthday).
When I click on the "Log In with Facebook" button, the popup changes to a blank screen, although the url 
shows https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request without any of the additional parameters.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Here is the javascript and below that the html that I'm using to open the facebook dialogue box:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
/*
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: '<my app id>',
                                    channelUrl: '<MY SITE ADDRESSS>/channel.html',");
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
        });



        function CheckIfPreExistingFBLogin(response) {
            alert("check if pre existing fb login");
            if (response.authResponse) {
                alert("pre existing fb login active");
                //user is already logged in and connected
                FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                    jQuery('#<%=hdnFBUID.ClientID%>').val(response.id);
                    jQuery('#<%=hdnFBemail.ClientID%>').val(response.email);
                    jQuery('#<%=hdnFBFirstName.ClientID%>').val(response.first_name);
                    jQuery('#<%=hdnFBLastName.ClientID%>').val(response.last_name);
                    jQuery('#<%=hdnFBBirthday.ClientID%>').val(response.birthday);
                    jQuery('#<%=hdnFBPreExistingLogin.ClientID%>').val("y");
                    alert("CheckIfPreExistingFBLogin got FB data - UserID=" + response.id);
                    PostItBack();
                });
            } else {
                alert("pre existing fb login is not active");
                //user is not connected to your app or logged out
                //do nothing
            }
        }

        function CheckForNewFBLogin(response) {
            alert("try to check for new fb login");
            if (response.authResponse) {
                alert("got a new FB login");
                FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                    jQuery('#<%=hdnFBUID.ClientID%>').val(response.id);
                    jQuery('#<%=hdnFBemail.ClientID%>').val(response.email);
                    jQuery('#<%=hdnFBFirstName.ClientID%>').val(response.first_name);
                    jQuery('#<%=hdnFBLastName.ClientID%>').val(response.last_name);
                    jQuery('#<%=hdnFBBirthday.ClientID%>').val(response.birthday);
                    jQuery('#<%=hdnFBPreExistingLogin.ClientID%>').val("n");
                    alert("Check for newFBLogin got FB data - UserID=" + response.id);
                    PostItBack();
                });
                //user is already logged in and connected
                // PostItBack();

            } else {
                alert("no new FB login");
                //user is not connected to your app or logged out
                //do nothing
            }
            }
        }

        function PostItBack() {
            __doPostBack('', 'gotLogin');
        }



        // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
        FB.getLoginStatus(CheckIfPreExistingFBLogin); //updateButton1
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', CheckForNewFBLogin);
    };


    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol
    + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    });
    */
</script>

and here is the code for the facebook login button in the body of the form:


<div id="fb-root" "></div>

<div class="fb-login-button" scope="user_birthday, user_about_me"> Login with Facebook </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to this bug: [FB.login does not trigger callback + does not close itself on localhost:8080](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/380566711996797), which is reported fixed now.